# How can we send bulk_email in django using different from_emails?

Tags: django

I have 1 Django app and i want to send bulk_email to multiple users, so normally it will send from only 1 from_email. Now how can I send bulk_email from different from_email when I select 1 email from the dropdown list?

```
from django.core import mail
connection = mail.get_connection()

connection.open()
reciever_list= ['aa@bb.cc', 'dd@ee.ff']  #extend this list according to your requirement
email1 = mail.EmailMessage('Hello', 'Body goes here', 'from@example.com',
                          reciever_list, connection=connection)
email1.send()
connection.close()
```

Comment: i guess this might help you https://medium.com/ibisdev/manage-multiple-email-services-with-django-a2391a38f67c

Comment: Please add your code which you use to send emails from. If you're using the `send_mail` [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/email/#send-mail), you can pass in a `from_email` value.

Comment: I have made change please check. See now I want to send emails from different from_email, as from frontend i have a dropdown which contains 4 emails. Now if i select first email the email should be going from the first from_email and if i select second email the email should be going from second from_email and so on. I want the different from_emails. I hope it should be clear now. @DMalan

Comment: Do you have code for your dropdown and your view that will handle the request from the form? Please add it here.

Comment: No i dont have yet but its the requirement to implement. So is it possible to handle from backend? @DMalan

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you gone through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/)?

Comment: Yes, I have checked, but I have to send bulk_email using different from_emails. So how can I give different configurations of email in settings.py as we by default use only one configuration in the settings.py file? 

I hope you are getting my point. @DMalan

Comment: In the example above, you're passing in `'from@example.com'` as a parameter to `EmailMessage`. I don't see where you are using settings for from emails?

Comment: Yes so that's my question can I use the static emails without giving the email configuration in settings.py? @DMalan

Comment: You're already doing it in the code above.

Comment: I have only written static for example purpose I am not sure if it works or not, and if I use static 'from@example.com' so it is compulsory to give configuration in settings.py?  @DMalan